# Changing a datetime column into time elapsed in R add number 19 to "hh"

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, datetime, duration

I imported an .xlsx file in R and created a data frame with it called "bike_data". In the .xlsx file is a column "ride_length" which measures the amount of time that has elapsed between the start and end date of a ride, expressed in Excel as hh:mm:ss. When this column was created in the data frame it was converted to a POSIX time stamp with the value "1899-12-31 hh:mm:ss"

using the functions hms() and strftime() have returned results that replace the "00" in the "hh" part of the stamp with "19"

the code I've used were formatted as foillows:

```
bike_data$ride_length<-as_hms(bike_data$ride_length)

bike_data$ride_length<-strftime(bike_data$ride_length, format = "%H:%M%S")
```

in both examples, a field that would read "1899-12-31 00:10:25" will now read "19:10:25" instead of "00:10:25"

Since I assume this change will affect my plotting, how can I alter the column to read "hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you imported the data from the Excel file, the ride_length column was interpreted as a time duration from a date-time origin that corresponds to "1899-12-30". That's why you see this date in the POSIX time stamp.

The hms() function from the hms package creates an object of class hms that represents a duration with hours, minutes, and seconds. By default, hms() interprets the input as a time of day, so it adds 24 hours to times that are less than 24 hours. That's why you see "19" instead of "00" in the output.

To get the duration in the format "hh:mm:ss", you can convert the hms object back to a character string using the format() function, like this:

```
bike_data$ride_length <- as_hms(bike_data$ride_length)
bike_data$ride_length <- format(bike_data$ride_length, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

PS: Is this the Cyclistic case study?

Comment: This is the cyclistic Case study! How'd you guess? Am I reading your code correctly? I should convert it using hms, then change the format?

Comment: Yup that should work! And I know because I'm also working on the same case study lol. Good luck man!